Azure CI/CD pipeline "Sequence contains more than one matching element"
I have an Azure devops pipeline setup to build and deploy a docker image to our azure container registry.
The application is a simple file generator that gets hosted in an Azure web app. When a new docker image is built the pipeline pushes it to the azure container registry and then a webhook fires telling the web app to restart and download the new image and start running again.
I have recently ran into an issue where if i push more than one change to the application in a single day when the web app attempts to startup on the second download it throws this error:

16/12/2024 14:55:13.827 ERROR - Site: thermalfilegenerator - Unable to start container. Error message: Sequence contains more than one matching element.

This error stops the container from running and the only fix I have been able to find is to create a brand new image repository in the azure container registry and then create a new web hook to the application and everything works as intended.
Has anyone else ran into this issue am I missing something in this pipeline? Thanks for all the help in advance!
I have looked through Microsoft's documentation and I have not been able to find any information regarding this. Also something to mention is that it just started happening out of nowhere. For a while I was able to push updates and everything would work as intended then one day it just start acting as described.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
